# how to set another field value in same row

Tags: javascript

Given a grid with 5 columns and an array of the IDs in column 2 how do you set the boolean value of column 1 to true for the IDs in the array? There are 25 rows and 5 of the rows are in the array.

```
var ProductIDArray = [2,5,9,12,16]; 
var i; 
for (i = 0; i < ProductIDArray.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("chk").checked = true; 
}
```

Comment: truth has been spoken

Comment: Column 1 is a checkbox column. Columns 2 is the ProductID. The array has the ProductIDs. How do you check the checkbox in column 1 for all the rows listed in the array?

Comment: It may help if you show us some of your code.

Comment: Columns are not a data structure in JavaScript, you can implement something like columns and rows by using a 2D array. Please show us what you mean by "checkbox column.", is this an array with id's to all the checkboxes in the DOM? If so you can go through it as set the property to checked.

Comment: How do you insert code blocks?
var ProductIDArray = [2,5,9,12,16];

var i;

for (i = 0; i < ProductIDArray.length; i++) {

    document.getElementById("chk").checked = true;

}

Comment: just indent your code with four spaces in the question

Comment: Why would you check the same element five times?

Comment: Column 1 is a checkbox column. Only the ones in the array should have the checkbox checked. The other rows shouldn't have column 1 checked.

Comment: Your code is checking the same element.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake: you can't/shouldn't have duplicate IDs on the page. Either use classes, or make those IDs unique for each element.

Second mistake: you need to check different element each time in the loop.

---

Based on this:

> Column 1 is a checkbox column. Only the ones in the array should have the checkbox checked. The other rows shouldn't have column 1 checked.

Let's try to fix it. Assuming that your checkbox IDs are `chk_N` where `N` is the number that matches the product ID (`chk_1`, `chk_2`, etc...), the code should look like this:

```
var ProductIDArray = [2,5,9,12,16]; 
var i; 
for (i = 0; i < ProductIDArray.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("chk_" + ProductIDArray[i]).checked = true; 
}
```

---

Here's an example:

```js
var ProductIDArray = [2, 5, 9, 12, 16];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < ProductIDArray.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("chk_" + ProductIDArray[i]).checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_11" />11<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_2" />2<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_33" />33<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_45" />45<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_65" />65<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_5" />5<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_16" />16<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_9" />9<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_12" />12<br>
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't get this to format correctly like in the previous post. The data returned in the grid varies so the ProductID isn't neccessarily 1-25. For instance if what is displayed in the grid are ProductIDs 2,5,6-23 then the values ProductID:i would equal the following. (2:0),(5:1),(6:2),(7:3),(8:4),(9:5) etc

Comment: The order doesn't matter, let me update my code to show you. Are you using a server-side language to generate the checkboxes?

Comment: correction The data returned in the grid varies so the ProductID isn't neccessarily 1-25. For instance if what is displayed in the grid are ProductIDs 2,5,6-23 then the values ProductID:i would equal the following. (2:0),(5:1),(9:2),(12:3),(16:4) The checkbox column is client side.

Comment: Oh, so it's the order in the array? Just one line needs changing then: `document.getElementById("chk_" + ProductIDArray[i]).checked = true;` into `document.getElementById("chk_" + i).checked = true;`